# Show plan before each section except the first one

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I wanted to show a plan before every section in my presentation, so I have added the following code before `\begin{document}`

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
 \begin{frame}<beamer>
 \frametitle{Plan}
 \tableofcontents[currentsection]
 \end{frame}
}
```

Now I would like to always do that **except the first section**, does anyone know how to deal with this exception?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Put the code you've mentioned after the `\section` to which you want it to apply from, rather than in the preamble

```
...
\section{Not in the list}
...
\AtBeginSection[]
  {
     \begin{frame}<beamer>
     \frametitle{Plan}
     \tableofcontents[currentsection]
     \end{frame}
  }
\section{First in the list}
```

Comment: It worked for me only when applying  it BEFORE the \section

Comment: Did not work for me but 

\AtBeginSection[]
{
 \begin{frame}{Lecture Overview}
 \tableofcontents[currentsection]
 \end{frame}
}
 
did

Answer (score 17):

I'm late to the party, but the solution by Joseph Wright does not help if you want to add that part to a beamer style.

A hack that I came up with:

```
\AtBeginSection[]
  {
    \ifnum \value{framenumber}>1
      \begin{frame}<beamer>
      \frametitle{Plan}
      \tableofcontents[currentsection]
      \end{frame}
    \else
    \fi
  }
```

This just checks if the `framenumber` is larger than `1` before printing the frame at the begin of each section. If the appearance of the first section is later than that, just switch the number to the appropriate one.

Comment: Just use \value{section} then you do not need to manually adapt the number